# Range of Unsigned & Signed int

Tags: c, integer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **args){
 int d=4294967295;
 unsigned e= -1;
 printf("\n%u\n%d\n%d\n%u\n%lu\n",d,d,e,e,sizeof(int));

 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4294967295
-1
-1
4294967295
4
```

Question is, if both `signed` and `unsigned` integers can be used to display all kinds of integers by just applying a suitable format string, what's the need for `unsigned` in the first place?

Comment: unsigned int e, you forgot to declare e as int

Comment: The int is optional in this case - declaring as unsigned is fine.

Comment: @AdelAhmed `unsigned` means `unsigned int`

Comment: oh that's good to know

Comment: Nothing says that a machine has to use two-complement binary to implement integer numbers, or that the bit-pattern for signed `-1` has to be the same as for unsigned `4294967295`. Then there's of course the actual programming using signed or unsigned numbers... The compiler do enforce some strictness, and it also gives some hints to the *reader* of the program about the ranges.

Comment: Unsigned int will ever be >= 0. You are printing -1 with %u, hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MayankVerma if you think there is no need of `unsigned`, please tell me whether the `int` value `0xFFFFFFFF` when cast to `int64_t` should have the decimal value `4294967295` or `-1`. Which should it be?

Comment: ... and when you divide the `int` value `0xFFFFFFFE` by 2, should the result be the decimal value `2147483648` or `-1`?

Comment: Compile with *warnings enabled* (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) and your compiler will do a really good job explaining it to you. In fact you should always compile with *warnings enabled*.

Comment: I get your point @WeatherVane.

Comment: Suggest, when compiling to enable all warnings.  For gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99`   The `-Wconversion` parameter will cause the compiler to tell you about an `implicit conversion` operations, that you probably want to use casts to make them explicit conversions.  The `-std=c99` tells the compiler which C language standard to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in so far as (on machines using two's complement and having 32 bit ints) the `0xFFFFFFFF` is displayed as `-1` with `%d`, but as `4294967295` with `%u`.

But strictly speaking this is undefined behaviour.

But the real difference between signed and unsigned variables is in their arithmetic interpretation. The main differences are

- with comparing: -1 < 0, but 0 < 4294967295.
- with multiplication and division.

Comment: One question, though. By "undefined" do you mean "unpredictable" or "architecture dependent"? I'm asking this, because I'm getting predictable answers at least for an x86-64 system.

Comment: @MayankVerma "Undefined behaviour" is a C language term. It means that the behaviour of the program is undefined if a certain technique is applied. Maybe you get predictable results, and probably they remain the same after each invocation, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @MayankVerma The edit about type casting is not to the point. The list above is supposed to list the different ways of how you can *observe* the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`Unsigned` can hold a larger positive value, and no negative value. `Unsigned` uses the leading bit as a part of the value, while the signed version uses the left-most-bit to identify if the number is positive or negative. Signed integers can hold both positive and negative numbers.

Comment: While "Unsigned uses the leading bit as a part of the value" is very common, it s not defined by C.  `UINT_MAX` could equal `INT_MAX`.